# How to append script tag in current page in MVC using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

For a requirement, i have rendered a script code and I need to append the rendered  code in the current page in MVC  using C# code. How can i achieve it?
e.g: [image: script tag added]

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "append"? Can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

**1** -You can use a section :

```
 @if (IsSectionDefined("myCustomScript"))
    { 
      @RenderSection("myCustomScript")
 }
```

**2** - just add the javascript code directly to the view.

**3** - Or you can insert your script into a JS file and declare a bundle
in your application. You would render it using:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyScript")
```

**4-** You can render a Partial inside your view wherever you want:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyScript")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place your script in a partial view and then render your partial view.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Script")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout page you could add

```
 @RenderSection("PageSpecificSecretScript", false)
```

and in view

```
@section PageSpecificSecretScript{

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

}
```